# Register generic ICacheManager using an IoC container (Ninject)

Tags: c#, ninject, cachemanager

This is for the [CacheManager](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager) library by Michah Conrad. In his example, he creates a cache manager using the CacheFactory.Build method, as seen here:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        var cache = CacheFactory.Build("todos", settings =>
        {
            settings
                .WithSystemRuntimeCacheHandle("inprocess");
        });
        container.RegisterInstance(cache);
    }
}
```

My question, is it possible to register the ICacheManger interface so that any property dependencies of any type will be automatically created by the IoC container?

Say I have this class

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Inject]
    public ICacheManager<string> StringCacheManager { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public ICacheManager<int> IntCacheManager { get; set; }
}
```

How could I set up my Ninject kernel to bind the generic ICacheManager interface so that it resolves using the types in MyClass?

Something like this, but that actually works:

```
kernel.Bind<ICacheManager<T>>().ToMethod((context) =>
{
    return CacheFactory.FromConfiguration<T>("defaultCache");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Answered my own question. This is how you do it:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(ICacheManager<>)).ToMethod((context) =>
{
    // GenericArguments holds the actual type for ICacheValue used in the ICachManager property or argument
    return CacheFactory.FromConfiguration(context.GenericArguments[0], "defaultCache");
});
```

Edit 2015-11-20:

As Micha pointed out, we have to use InSingletonScope at the end to force it to keep the instance that it creates throughout the lifetime of the application. The reason for this is because each instance of CacheManager will have it's own cache because the keys are prefixed with the CacheManager instance's unique id. So, even if you're using a shared cache like System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache, CacheManager will create new instances of it.

Comment: don't forget to use singleton ;) Otherwise Ninject creates a new cache instance every time you instantiate MyClass. .InSingletonScope() should work